# kpathsea-warning when using filenames containing $&?

Tags: errors, tex-core, kpathsea

The MWE, `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{A$&1file.tex}
Hello, World!
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\input{A$&1file.tex}
\end{document}
```

The MWE does not contain calls to `\write18`.

The filename `A$&1file.tex` is fine with many file-systems.

Nevertheless compiling the MWE delivers the following warning twice (once when processing the `filecontents*`-environment; once when processing the `\input`-command) to the console but not to the .log-file:

```
warning: kpathsea: A$&1file.tex: Unrecognized variable construct `$&'.
```

Why?

Is/where is this behavior documented?  Is this a bug?

(Besides these warnings everything seems to compile fine.
The resulting .pdf-file and auxiliary files look as expected by me.)

---

Here is the output to console:

```
$ pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))warning: kpathsea: A$&1file.tex: Unrecognized variable construct `$&'.


LaTeX Warning: Writing file `./A$&1file.tex'.


(./test.aux)warning: kpathsea: A$&1file.tex: Unrecognized variable construct `$&'.
warning: kpathsea: A$&1file.tex: Unrecognized variable construct `$&'.
 (./A$&1file.tex) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.
map}] (./test.aux) )</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/
cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 12015 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

---

Here is the .log-file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.2.13)  21 JUL 2020 00:35
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)

LaTeX Warning: Writing file `./A$&1file.tex'.

\openout15 = `A$&1file.tex'.


(./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
 (./A$&1file.tex) [1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 204 strings out of 494412
 2170 string characters out of 6172415
 55258 words of memory out of 5000000
 3979 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 59 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,4n,17p,112b,314s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/share/
texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 12015 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 12 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: kpathsea supports usage of shell variables which have to be expanded to load a file, but `$&` is not a valid shell variable (search for `kpathsea_var_expand`)

Comment: @HenriMenke Why? When writing via `\write18` to the shell I expect the _shell_ to support usage of shell variables. But I don't expect such things when not addressing the shell but accessing the file-system by commands like `\openout`, `\closeout`, `\input`. How to access files whose names/filepaths contain things that look like valid shell-variables?

Comment: I guess it is to support things like `\openin\readfile="$HOME/test.txt"`.  Better ask on the TeX Live list or Karl directly.

Comment: @HenriMenke odd thing is that openin does this but not openout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you get this from `\openin`

```
\message{in   }
\immediate\openin5="A$&1file.tex"

\message{out   }

\immediate\openout5="A$&1file.tex"
\immediate\write5{zzz}
\immediate\closeout5
\bye
```

produces

```
 in warning: kpathsea: A$&1file.tex: Unrecognized variable construct `$&'.
 out  )
```

latex does the openin to check for `\ifeof` as part of its checks on over-writing the file.

Worth reporting to the texk list I think.

Comment: If you expect me to report that, then I will be glad about some pointer to that list so I can find out more about it and about how to report something there.

Comment: @UlrichDiez https://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-k